# Unused Classes in Programming Frameworks

Tags: php, python, frameworks

In a programming framework, what happens to unused classes that exist but is never called upon?

Will they have no impact on the performance since they're never called?

Or will they sit there, do nothing and cause performance downgrade?

Comment: they slowly become self-aware and take over the world

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They will only take up a bit more memory space and add a bit to the overhead initializing time for defining the class. They will not affect runtime speeds.

Example:

```
import time
t1 = time.time()

class A:
    def __init__(self):
        pass

>>> print time.time() - t1
0.00399994850159
```

**VS**

```
import time
t1 = time.time()

>>> print time.time() - t1
0.000999927520752
```